# Is there any way to detect when a Swiffy animation has completed?

Tags: javascript, flash, dom-events, google-swiffy

Do Swiffy animations trigger an event when they're complete? Or is there perhaps a way to grab the current frame vs. total frames?

I tried de-minifying runtime.js as mentioned in another Stack Overflow post, but I can't decipher it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this post, I found a solution. I ended up using a getURL() call at the end of my FLA. It looks like this:

```
getURL("javascript:animationIsComplete();");
```

Put whatever you want in the animationIsComplete() function and it will now be triggered at the end of the Swiffy animation.

Answer (score 2):

Flash timeline frame script:

```
   import flash.net.navigateToURL;
   import flash.net.URLRequest;

   navigateToURL(new URLRequest("javascript:document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('animation_done', {detail:{name:'sparkle'}}))"), "_self");
   stop();
```

Javascript:

```
 document.addEventListener("animation_done", animationDone, false);

 function animationDone(e /* Event */){
     console.log('animation done ' + e.detail.name);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles across this question and is working with ActionScript 3 - the top answer will not work for them, as the getURL() function is only available in ActionScript 2 and earlier versions.

Use the following for ActionScript 3:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("javascript:your_function()"), "_self");
```

Add that as an action to the final frame of your animation in Flash and then convert it using Swiffy. You can then take the output from Swiffy and work it into a webpage. Just make sure you define your JavaScript function somewhere in the source of the page that displays the Swiffy animation.